# Coordinates of cell in Excel

Tags: c, excel

I'm trying to get coordinates from Excel cell-numbers like A5, AC8, AAA8, and DADFAF145.

I read input from the user like this:

```
while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
```

In the cycle I have a condition

```
if( c >= 48 && c <= 57 )
    {
      ungetc( c, stdin );
      scanf( "%d\n", &column ); }
```

It check if c is a number 0-9, returns c to the buffer and read the  number. The number is the y coordinate.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the X coordinate from the characters. I can't figure out an algorithm.

Index of A = 0, Z = 25, total 26 chars. If there is one char, it's ok. I dont' know how to solve if there are more chars.

Some examples:

```
A5
 => [5,0]

Z8
 => [8,25]

AAA2345

 => [2345,702]       (26+26*26)
PA12
 => [12,416]         (26+15*26)


AC23
 => [23,28]

NBFA349
 => [349,247572]
```

Comment: So you are looking for a C function which, when fed a string like "NBFA" returns 247572?

Comment: Why do you want to close this? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Also -- why would A5 translate to [5,0]? Wouldn't it be either [4,0] or [5,1]? It seems inconsistent for your rows to be indexed as 1-based but your columns 0-based.

Comment: If A is 0, then how is AAA 702?

Comment: @Levin, please try to answer the follow-up questions other people ask. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I think you should post the whole code, you are using a very wierd logic apparently.

Comment: If you can find a base26 to base10 converter, you'll be 90% of the way there. just map A=0, B=1, C=2...J=9, K=A, L=B, M=C, N=D, etc, then convert to base 10.

Comment: Index of Excel table start from 0, B = 1, C = 2 ..... but if AA it's 26, becouse Z index is 25 and continue... for better view, open Excel a watch to cell

Comment: @Levin -- the standard in Excel is to start with A = 1, B = 2, ...The function given below can of course be adjust by subtracting 1 before returning -- but then is still seems inconsistent the way you want to treat the rows.

Comment: You are asking for cell coordinates, but Excel 2007-2013 has only 16,384 columns.  So what do you want for columns past `XFD` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These letter combinations are actually base-26, however the digits are not from 0 to 25, but 1 to 26 instead (and are represented by letters from A to Z). So you can move from the end of the string to the beginning, multiply the digit (`str[i]-'A'+1` where `str[i]` is the i-th character of the string `str`, i runs from `strlen(str)` to 0) to the corresponding power of 26. Like that:

```
int c = 1, s = 0;
for(int i = strlen(str)-1; i>=0; i--) {
    s += (str[i]-'A'+1)*c; c*=26;
}
```

You must move from right to left, because, for example, number 28 is written as `AB` (and not `BA`)

Comment: Great, thank you! The coordinate will be in s right?

Answer (score 0):

The following might help. It defines a function which returns the column number of a string like "ADX". It coincides with what you will see if you enter the function `=Column()` in a cell in that column in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long col_num(char* col);

int main(void){
    char test1[] = "Z";
    char test2[] = "AA";
    char test3[] = "BZA";
    printf("Column %s is column number %ld\n",test1,col_num(test1));
    printf("Column %s is column number %ld\n",test2,col_num(test2));
    printf("Column %s is column number %ld\n",test3,col_num(test3));
    return 0;
}

long col_num(char* col){
    long sum, i, n, p, val;
    char letter;
    n = strlen(col);
    sum = 0;
    p = 1;
    for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        letter = col[i]; 
        val = letter - 'A' + 1;
        sum += p*val;
        p *= 26;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I almost forgot. Output:

```
Column Z is column number 26
Column AA is column number 27
Column BZA is column number 2029
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//"A" => 1, "Z" -> 26, "AAA" => 703, "NBFA" => 247573
int colToNum (const char *s){
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; s[i] ; ++i)
        n = n * 26  + (s[i] - 'A' + 1);
    return n;//To zero origin : return n-1;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the carry of the advance number? E.g 0,1,2,3...9,10 : 1(0..9, one 10 number hold)0,,like  A,B...Y,Z, AA : A(one 26 hold)A